# Filter a request within a request in a RESTFUL quarkus applicaiton

Tags: java, jax-rs, servlet-filters, quarkus

I have a quarkus(jax-rs) application. I am using ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter to filter requests and responses in my application.

My main issue is within a post request i have another post request to a URl. My filter works fine on my main post request method. But i also want it to detect that there is another post request within that request so i can also filter it. It cannot seem to detect that, any ideas/solutions on why this is happening?

**Here is an example of whats happening:**

```
@POST
  @Path("/send/{profile}")
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  public Response x(Request request) {
    final Hello hello = helloMapper.toHelloReuqest(request);
    final Hello response= helloer.send(hello);
  .....
```

**Within the send method:**

```
Response webtextResponse = webtextclient.sendHello(a,b)
.....
```

**within webtextclient:**

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "xyz")
@ApplicationScoped
public interface WebTextClient {
  @POST
  @Path("/send_hello.html")
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
  @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
  Response sendHello(@FormParam("a") String a, @FormParam("b") String b);
}
```

Comment: How is that inner request performed? Does it mean that you initialize a JAX-RS client instance within the method and use it to call a different REST method on the same server? If that were the case, I see no reason why that wouldn't get filtered. So I guess you're doing it some different way.

Comment: Can you take take a look of my updated post @JanMartiška

Comment: The server-side implementation for `WebTextClient` is a REST resource or something else? Given that you have `@Path("/send_hello.html")` in your client, it sounds like you're using the client to retrieve a static HTML file rather than call a REST endpoint, but in that case, REST filters don't apply.